# Export Excel in Laravel

Tags: laravel, export-to-excel, maatwebsite-excel

**I have a problem with passing parameters on export file, I want to filter the export according to date selected on page. Hope you help me with this issue. Thanks **

> This is my ExportController, I request data from form to my controller to give the export collection a date.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Exports\ExportAttendance;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
class ExportController extends Controller
{

    
    public function export(Request $request)
    {
     
      
        return Excel::download(new ExportAttendance($request->input('min'),$request->input('max')),'Attendance.xlsx');
    }
}
```

> This is my ExportAttendance.php, this is responsible for the exportation of collections. On the query function I want to filter the data according on the date requested on the controller. How could I passed a data from controller to my Export.php, I did used constructors but it always return errors.

```
public function headings():array{
        return[
            
            'Name',
            'In (AM)',
            'Out (AM)',
            'In (PM)',
            'Out (PM)',
            'Meeting',
            'Task',
            'Note',
            'Total Hours',
            'Date'

        ];
    }
    public function query()
    { 
        $start = "2021-06-14";
        $end = "2021-06-14";

        return Attendance::select('Name','InAm','OutAM','InPM','OutPM','Meeting','SpecialTask','Undertime','TotalHours','Date')->whereBetween('Date',[$start,$end]);
    }
    public function collection()
    {
        
        return Attendance::all();

    }
    public function map($attendance):array
    {
        return[
            $attendance->Name,
            $attendance->InAM,
            $attendance->OutAM,
            $attendance->InPM,
            $attendance->OutPM,
            $attendance->Meeting,
            $attendance->SpecialTask,
            $attendance->Undertime,
            $attendance->TotalHours,
            $attendance->Date,
        ];
   
      
    }
```

Comment: What error did you see?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the $request object to the export class. You can simply use the `request` helper method.

```php
public function query()
    { 
        return Attendance::select('Name','InAm','OutAM','InPM','OutPM','Meeting','SpecialTask','Undertime','TotalHours','Date')
            ->whereBetween('Date',[request('start'), request('end')]);
    }
```

Passing parameters is supposed to work too. Pls let me know what errors you see so I can update my answer.

I used Constructor

```php
    public function query()
        { 
            $start = "2021-06-14";
            $end = "2021-06-14";
    return Attendance::select('Name','InAm','OutAM','InPM','OutPM','Meeting','SpecialTask','Undertime','TotalHours','Date')->where('Date','=',$this->year);
}
```

And this is my controller,

```php
    public function export(Request $request)
        {
          ob_start();
          $datestart = $request->input('min');
          $datestart = ob_get_contents();
         
        
          return Excel::download(new ExportAttendance($datestart),'Attendance.xlsx');
          ob_end_flush();
    
    }
```

Another problem arise, when I used ob_end_clean() all my variable values returned nulls.

Comment: public function export(Request $request)
    {
      ob_start();
      $datestart = $request->input('min');
      var_dump($datestart);
      ob_end_clean();
      return Excel::download(new ExportAttendance(strval($datestart)),'Attendance.xlsx');
    }

Comment: when I used ob_end_clean() it cleans all my values, why is that? how can I retain my values while using this clean? Please enlighten me.